# How to compute $P(W>0| X+W=u)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to compute
\begin{align}
P(W>0| X+W=u)
\end{align}
where $X$ and $W$ are independent standard normal.

I am asked to do this via Baye' Rule.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I am not sure how to use both probabilities and probability density function is Baye's rule.  For example, is $P(W>0|X+W=u)=\frac{P(W>0) f_{X+W|W}(u|W>0)}{f_{X+W}(u)}$ correct? I don't think this is.

Comment: For a solution with (almost) no computation, note that $$U=\frac{W+X}{\sqrt 2}\qquad V=\frac{X-W}{\sqrt 2}$$ defines a standard i.i.d. random vector $(U,V)$ hence one is after $$P(U>V\mid U=\sqrt2 u)=P(V<\sqrt2 u\mid U=\sqrt2 u)=P(V<\sqrt2 u)=\Phi(\sqrt2 u)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First try to compute for $y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$f_{W|X+W}(y|u)$$
Then the result you desire will be obtained by integrating wrt $y$ from $0$ to $\infty$. Let me know if you need additional help.

Also $f_{X+W|W}(y|u)=f_{X}(y-u)$ as $X$ and $W$ are independent.